# diff -I (uppercase 'i') not working when options are passed as variable

Tags: shell, unix, diff, gnu

I'm writing a script to find out the diff between files using the GNU version of the `diff` command. Here I need to ignore the html comment <!-- and any patterns (provided as input through a file) that is matched.

File `wxy/a`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">
some text here
           <property name="loginUrl" value="http://localhost:15040/ab/ssoLogin"/>
     <!--property name="cUrl" value="http://localhost:15040/ab/ssoLogin" /-->
</beans>
```

File `xyz/a`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">
some text there
           <property name="loginUrl" value="http://localhost:15045/ab/ssoLogin"/>
     <!--property name="cUrl" value="http://localhost:15045/ab/ssoLogin" /-->
</beans>
```

Pattern input file: `input.conf`:

```
[a]
http://.*[:0-9]*/ab/ssoLogin
[some other file]
....
....
```

My script would read the input.conf for the filename [a] and puts to a temp file lines_to_ignore, now I read the file lines_to_ignore and append the pattern to a variable like below

`compare_file.sh`

```
diff_ignore_options="-I \"\!--\"" # Ignore option for <!-- Comments

for iline in `cat lines_to_ignore`; do
    diff_ignore_options=${diff_ignore_options}" -I \"$iline\""
    echo "-----------------------------------------------------------"
    diff -I "\!--" -I "$iline" wxy/a xyz/a
    echo "-----------------------------------------------------------"
done

diff $diff_ignore_options wxy/a xyz/a
```

Now the output:

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
19c19
< some text here
---
> some text there
-----------------------------------------------------------

19,21c19,21
< some text here
<            <property name="loginUrl" value="http://localhost:15040/ab/ssoLogin"/>
<      <!--property name="cUrl" value="http://localhost:15040/ab/ssoLogin" /-->
---
> some text there
>            <property name="loginUrl" value="http://localhost:15045/ab/ssoLogin"/>
>      <!--property name="cUrl" value="http://localhost:15045/ab/ssoLogin" /-->
```

Why is the variable substitution in diff command not working?

```
diff $diff_ignore_options wxy/a xyz/a
```

I want to do it the variable way because I might have to match more than one pattern in some files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the `!` character, which the shell uses for history expansion. Furthermore, you're including escaped double-quote characters in your `$diff_ignore_options` variable; since the pattern you want to ignore doesn't include any `"` characters, you don't want that.

This should work (note the use of single quotes to avoid treating `!` as a metacharacter):

```
diff_ignore_options='-I !--'
diff $diff_ignore_options this_file that_file
```

And you can then add more patterns like this:

```
diff_ignore_options="$diff_ignore_options -I foobar"
```

Comment: @rtv: I see you're new to Stack Overflow. Welcome! "Thanks a lot" is usually expressed by an upvote (clicking the up arrow next to the answer). "It worked" is usually expressed by accepting an answer (clicking the check mark). (Neither is mandatory, of course.) See http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask And you're welcome, of course.

Comment: Ok, no problem; you should be there soon. (To be clear, my aim is to let you know how things work; I'm not trolling for points, which would be poor style).

Comment: and with a couple +1's let the voting begin! Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: If any of your option arguments contain whitespace, this technique will be insufficient. Bash (and ksh and zsh ...) has arrays that will protect elements with spaces: `diff_opts=(-I 'this and that'); diff "${diff_opts[@]}" f1 f2`